# Multi-line text on multirow

Tags: tabularx, multirow

How can I set text to be multi-line on a multirow table? I'm referring to row 5 column 1. Thank you

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
    |>{\hsize=1.0\hsize}C|% 10% of 4\hsize 
    >{\hsize=1.0\hsize}C|% 30% of 4\hsize
    >{\hsize=1.0\hsize}C|% 30% of 4\hsize 
       % sum=4.0\hsize for 4 columns
  }
\hline

\textbf{Instituição} & \textbf{Estágio} & \textbf{Duração}\\
\hline

\multirow{4}{*}{Hospital de Origem} & Radiologia convencional e estudos contrastados & 6 meses \\
 & Ecografia Geral e Ecografia Ginecológica & 6 meses \\
 & Eco-Doppler & 1 mês \\
 & Tomografia Computorizada & 6 meses \\
\hline

\multirow{3}{*}{Hospital de Origem depois} & Radiologia convencional e estudos contrastados & 3 meses \\
 & Neurorradiologia & 3 meses \\
 & Ressonância Magnética & 3 meses (a tempo parcial) \\
\hline

CHospital de Origem com texto grande (muito grande) & Eco-Doppler & 2 meses \\
\hline

\multirow{4}{*}{Hospital de Origem enorme e acontece isto porque} & Radiologia Mamária & 3 meses \\
 & Medicina Nuclear e Densitometria Óssea & 1 mês \\
 & Radiologia do Pescoço &  0\\
 & Radiologia de intervenção &  0\\
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\caption{Distribuição do Internato de Formação Específica}
\label{tab:exemplo}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your columns have a fixed width, you just have to use `=` as a width argument in the place of `*`. I took the opportunity to add some vertical padding at the top of cells, and simplified the tabularx preamble: the `\hsize=` argument is not necessary, since all columns have the same width.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|}
\hline

\textbf{Instituição} & \textbf{Estágio} & \textbf{Duração}\\
\hline

\multirow{5}{=}{\centering Hospital de Origem} & Radiologia convencional e estudos contrastados & 6 meses \\
 & Ecografia Geral e Ecografia Ginecológica & 6 meses \\
 & Eco-Doppler & 1 mês \\
 & Tomografia Computorizada & 6 meses \\
\hline

\multirow{3}{=}{\centering Hospital de Origem depois} & Radiologia convencional e estudos contrastados & 3 meses \\
 & Neurorradiologia & 3 meses \\
 & Ressonância Magnética & 3 meses (a tempo parcial) \\
\hline

CHospital de Origem com texto grande (muito grande) & Eco-Doppler & 2 meses \\
\hline

\multirow{5}{=}{\centering Hospital de Origem enorme e acontece isto porque} & Radiologia Mamária & 3 meses \\
 & Medicina Nuclear e Densitometria Óssea & 1 mês \\
 & Radiologia do Pescoço & 0\\
 & Radiologia de intervenção & 0\\
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\caption{Distribuição do Internato de Formação Específica}
\label{tab:exemplo}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]