# Aligning a Multi-line Expression in Table

Tags: tables, math-mode, vertical-alignment, align, tabularx

I am so close to having this aligned properly, but the right-most cell is flush against the top rule whereas the left-most and center cells have a small amount of vertical space.  I am trying to make the alignment uniform (either remove vertical space, or have it consistent across the row).

I've used `\parbox{}` to allow the multiline expression to be contained within, and horizontally aligned within, the table.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Title of Table.}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{1.4cm} p{6.9cm} p{6.8cm}} 
\toprule
Head1 & Head2 & Head3 \\
\midrule
text   & text text text text &  \parbox{6.8cm}{$BZ, CY, CX, BZ, BX, AY, AZ, \\ CY, CZ, \ldots$ } \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Also, in case this is important, I have the following in my preamble for APA-formatted tables.

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,labelfont=it,justification=justified,
  singlelinecheck=false,font=doublespacing}
```

Comment: in case you feel the answer has been helpful feel free  to accept the same by clicking the tick mark on the left side

Comment: Hi @jsbibra. Sorry, I should have tagged you in my previous comment.  I should have included more text in the middle column, as the amount I need (pasted into your example) makes it run wider than the page. I tried using p{width} instead of l, c, h, but this seems to produce the undesired vertical space.

Comment: I just did it the "hard way," without using mathematical expressions.

Comment: ...care to share this "hard way" with others?

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what you want to achieve, you should provide a complete minimal example.

Anyway, with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\captionsetup[table]{textfont=it,format=plain,justification=justified,
    singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=spaced,skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,labelfont=it,justification=justified,
    singlelinecheck=false,font=doublespacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Title of Table.}
        \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[1.4cm]Q[6.9cm]X[mode=math]}} 
            \toprule
            Head1 & Head2 & Head3 \\
            \midrule
            text   & text text text text & {BZ, CY, CX, \\ BZ, BX, AY,\\ AZ, CY, CZ, \ldots} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that a `tabularx` environment requires the use of an `X`-column in order to work properly. Without one, you might as well just use a regular `tabular`. Secondly, and what you're looking to change, a list of inline math elements are not breakable around `,`. You'll have to change how that is managed by using content from (say) [“Allowing line break at ',' in inline math mode” breaks citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19100/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19100/5764
\mathchardef\breakingcomma\mathcode`\,
{\catcode`,=\active
  \gdef,{\breakingcomma\discretionary{}{}{}}
}
\newcommand{\mathlist}[1]{\mathcode`\,=\string"8000 #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Table caption}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ p{14mm} p{69mm} X } 
    \toprule
    Head1 & Head2 & Head3 \\
    \midrule
    text & text text text text & $\mathlist{BZ, CY, CX, BZ, BX, AY, AZ, CY, CZ, \ldots}$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467445/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Title of Table.}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccC} 
            \toprule
            Head1 & Head2 & Head3 \\
            \midrule
            text   & text text text text &{{\parbox{3cm}{$BZ, CY, CX, BZ, BX,\\ AY, 
            AZ, CY, CZ, \ldots$ }}} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[h]
                \caption{Title of Table.}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccC} 
            \toprule
            Head1 & Head2 & Head3 \\
            \midrule
            text   & text text text text &  {{$BZ, CY, CX, BZ, BX, AY, AZ, CY, CZ, 
            \ldots$ }} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I should have included more text in the middle column, as the amount I need (pasted into your example) makes it run wider than the page.  I tried using p{width} instead of l, c, h, but this seems to produce the undesired vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

The baseline of a `\parbox` with multiple lines of text in it is the baseline of its bottommost row, giving the whole box excessive height above the baseline. Such a box is not aligned at the baseline but at the top, making it appear flush against the rule above.

The solution is to include a "strut" in its first line of text so that the (imaginary) baseline of its topmost row aligns with the baselines in the other columns. Plain TeX offers the macros `\strut` and `\mathstrut` for this.

```tex
text & \strut text text text text &
$\mathlist{\mathstrut BZ, CY, CX, BZ, BX, AY, AZ, CY, CZ, \ldots}$ \\
```

See also [Identical spacing of inference lines with Bussproofs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621047/identical-spacing-of-inference-lines-with-bussproofs/621056#621056).